# upgraded Angular project from 7 to 8, now not working in production

Tags: angular, upgrade

I have been developing my web app using angular 7 and thought i would upgrade to 8. Keep things up to date. Everything went well. All worked out using ng serve. So i continue developing my app.

I then publish my app. This is hosted in docker. When i now run it, the page loads as before but the controls dont seem to work correctly. Such as a drop down option list does not get populated, and my routing doesn't seem to work.

No errors are shown in browser (f12 - console)

What can i do, how can i found the problem. Again, all works ok from ng serve and it did work ok prior to upgrading in production mode.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

I have made sure i am running the latest:
angular,
"npm",
"node.js",
material,
"typeScript".

Comment: Check errors in network, if not then check the webserver error log

Comment: Can you post your routes configuration that is located in your app.module.ts?

Comment: Hi izeko, please be more specific about what you have done. Your question is very broad and is unlikely to find someone who faced an exactly same situation as you. May I suggest that you post more information, such as: what commands did you run to upgrade your Angular? What controls are not working? What npm packages (3rd party libs) are you using, specifically for your dropdown option? What routes are not working? Please try to narrow down your problems first and **post some code samples** so others are able to help you. Help us to want to help you!

Comment: Try local ng build --prod and see if it compiles okay with prod mode, also post your dockerfile, did you follow the upgrade guide?

Answer (score 1):

Routing was updated in the update from Angular 7 to Angular 8 if you are using lazy loading.

```
{path: ‘user’, loadChildren: ‘./users/user.module#UserModulee’}
```

should now be

```
{path: ‘user’, loadChildren: () => import(‘./users/user.module’).then(m => m.UserModule)};
```

Comment: Im pretty sure this was deprecated on v8, so its not a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply.

I dont use lazy loading. I have kind of fixed it.

I took on old backup i made in 7 and then copied my current app folder over the top of my 7 version. It now works.

I might see if i can upgrade again to 8.

Comment: Hi izeko, welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is a question and answer site for programming and computing related problems. It is not a forum. Please refrain from responding to your answerers by posting another answer such as this. Instead, please use this "add a comment" feature. You can delete this answer by pressing the "delete" button.